# Why there is no virus in Linux?

Tags: linux, virus

I heard that there is no virus in Linux.
The source code of Linux is freely available.
Then why nobody is creating virus in Linux?

Comment: Because it has such a small user base that the impact would not be very large.  There are many different flavors of linux, and a virus would only be able to target a specific one which would have limited impact.

Comment: Also, those who _do_ use linux are likely already more computer savvy and security conscious.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, there's hundreds of them..  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_malware

Comment: The assumption you make is 100% wrong : open source code doesn't mean more security flaws, usually it means less. Why ? Because more people are reviewing and fixing the code, proprietary software even in binary form are easily reversed engineered and are a lot less reviewed.

Comment: Linux viruses are based on the honor system. They require you to delete all your files yourself, and promise to email all your contacts and request they do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my understanding most viruses are written to attack the U.S. government and other organizations that run Microsoft Windows on the desktops, etc... so although I am sure it is possible to write Linux viruses, people are less inclined to do so. (Also sure it has to do with the number of people they can hit with Windows viruses vs. Linux viruses).